# Shell Script Exit Code - Unable to set

Tags: bash, shell, exit

I am running following test bash script:

test.sh

========

```
pass=$1
if [ $pass -eq 1 ]; then
   exit 0
else
   exit 1
fi
```

=============

So, If I run './test.sh 1', it should give me success code, i.e. 0. And if I run './test.sh 2' it should give me specific error code, i.e. 1.

But when I run the script, I am getting 0 as exit code for both the cases.

Output

========================

```
# ./test.sh 1 |echo $?
  0
# ./test.sh 2 |echo $?
  0
#
```

=========================

What am I doing wrong here?  Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Noman A.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your script works, your test is broken though. Don't use a pipe there.

```
# ./test.sh 1 ; echo $?
0
# ./test.sh 2 ; echo $?
1
```

What you proposed with a pipeline cannot work, because all the processes in pipeline are started "simultaneously". The shell starts a sub-shell to host each process (at least Bash does, implementations might vary -not sure about that), connects the input and output streams appropriately, then lets the OS schedule things as it sees fit.

So the rightmost process (in your case `echo $?`) is started at the "same time" as your test script. Therefore `$?` in that sub-shell (which will have been expanded before the actual process is started) can't possibly represent the return code from the test script - `t.sh` might not even have started yet!

See the Wikipedia article on [Unix Pipelines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_%28Unix%29) for some more information, or your shells documentation on pipelines. ([Bash Pipelines](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pipelines) for instance.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply Mat. But when I use echo inside the script as well instead of using pipe, it prints 0 for both.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that. Edit your question to show your new version and how you call it, or post a new question.

Comment: Sorry Mat, I used the test as posted by you and the result is fine. Can you please tell me what is the difference with using pipe instead?

Comment: @Noman Amir: edited my answer to clarify why the pipe approach cannot work.